# Display department names using Cursors.Create a PL/SQL block to display all the department names from the Department table using cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

TABLE:

```
Column name Data type Constraints

DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(5) PK
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL
LOCATION_ID VARCHAR2(15)
```

I have tried this. But still i didn’t get my output. Can somebody help me to get the output.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(25);
CURSOR dep_cursor IS
SELECT
DEPARTMENT_NAME
FROM
department;
BEGIN
OPEN dep_cursor;
FETCH dep_cursor INTO DEPARTMENT_NAME;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Department Names are :’ || DEPARTMENT_NAME);
CLOSE dep_cursor;
END;
/
```

Error message: Bind variable “~” not declared.

Sample output:

```
Department Names are :
ADMIN
DEVELOPMENT
TESTING
```

Comment: This appears to be a homework assignment, designed to start teaching some elementary PL/SQL.  From a practical standpoint, PL/SQL is not needed at all, just a simple 'select department_name from department' would have done it.  And a bit of advice on PL/SQL - do not name your local variables (ie: DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(25);) the same as the table column names.  Develop a naming standard that clearly identifies local variables and procedure parms distinctly from column names. Personally, I use 'v_' prefix for all local variables, and 'p_' prefix for all parms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about those "fancy" single quotes you used here:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Department Names are :’ || DEPARTMENT_NAME);
```

should be

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department Names are :' || DEPARTMENT_NAME);
```

---

As of other "errors" you've made: without a **loop**, cursor returns only one row and you then display it. I'd suggest you to switch to a cursor for loop as it is simpler to maintain:

```
begin
  for cur_r in (select department_name from department) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.department_name);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is everything you need; no declaration section, no opening nor closing a cursor, no worrying about exiting the loop ... Oracle does it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
v_dept department.department_name%type; 
cursor c_dept is SELECT department_name FROM department;
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('Department Names are :');
    OPEN c_dept;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_dept INTO v_dept;
        EXIT WHEN c_dept%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_dept);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_dept;
END;
/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

- 

> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
>   declare v_dept
> department.department_name%type;
>   cursor c_dept is SELECT
> department_name FROM department order by department_name asc;
> BEGIN   dbms_output.put_line('Department Names
> are :');
> OPEN c_dept;
> LOOP
> FETCH c_dept INTO v_dept;
> EXIT WHEN c_dept%notfound;
> dbms_output.put_line(v_dept);
> END LOOP;
> CLOSE c_dept; END;

- 

**This will 100% work as question is also asking to display in *Ascending order*.
Please up-vote if you find this useful**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare
v_dept department.department_name%type;
cursor c_dept is SELECT department_name FROM department ORDER  BY DEPARTMENT_NAME;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Department Names are :');
OPEN c_dept;
LOOP
FETCH c_dept INTO v_dept;
EXIT WHEN c_dept%notfound;
dbms_output.put_line(v_dept);
END LOOP;
CLOSE c_dept;
END;
/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
v_dept department.department_name%type;
cursor c_dept is SELECT department_name FROM department order by department_name asc;
BEGIN 
    dbms_output.put_line('Department Names are :');
        OPEN c_dept;
        LOOP
            FETCH c_dept INTO v_dept;
            EXIT WHEN c_dept%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_dept);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE c_dept; 
END;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: The only difference with the answer provided by @codex one year ago is the added ORDER BY in the cursor, and that point has been already addressed in other answers, so your answer is basically a duplicate of other answers.