# Write a PL/SQL block to display the department name and the total salary expenditure of the department from the Employee table

Tags: sql, oracle

Display the department name and the total salary expenditure of the department from the Employee table.

To find the department name and the salary of the person from the particular department must be the output.

```
THIS IS THE EMPLOYEE TABLE:

EMP_ID     EMP_NAME SALARY  DEPT
101         Tom     54000   MECH
102       William   43000   CSE
103         John    34560   MECH
104        Smith    56000   CSE
105        Steve    23450   IT
```

CODING:

I have tried this but i didn't get the output can somebody help me to get the output.

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
Dept varchar2(25);
Employee_salary VARCHAR2(25);
SELECT
Employee_salary
FROM
Employee;
WHERE salary=23450;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘Department-wise salary expenditure :’ || Dept salary);
END;
/
```

And the Sample Output:

```
Department-wise salary expenditure:
IT department, total salary is 48000
CSE department, total salary is 79000
MECH department, total salary is 80000
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't even compile. Presumably you got error messages when you tried to run it. For future reference you should include such errors in the question. Also, you should bookmark the Oracle PL/SQL manual. It has plenty of examples which which show you how to write programs like this. [Here is the chapter on using SQL in PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/static.htm#LNPLS006)

Comment: The same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/63647481/230471. The quote character is `'` not `’`.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR GUIDANCE SIR .I GOT THE OUTPUT

Answer (score 2):

```
set serveroutput on;
declare 
    cursor c_depts is select DEPT, sum(SALARY) as sumsal from employee group by DEPT;
    v_depts c_depts%rowtype;
begin
    open c_depts;
    dbms_output.put_line('Department-wise salary expenditure:');
    loop
       fetch c_depts into v_depts;
       exit when c_depts%notfound;
       dbms_output.put_line(v_depts.DEPT || ' department, total salary is ' || v_depts.sumsal );
    end loop;
    close c_depts;
end;
 /
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you help us understand it by explaining what the above code block does?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a loop (in PL/SQL) to display all departments. For example:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Department-wise salary expenditure:');
  3    for cur_r in (select dept, sum(salary) sumsal
  4                  from employee
  5                  group by dept
  6                  order by dept
  7                 )
  8    loop
  9      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(cur_r.dept, 4, ' ') ||
 10        ' department, total salary is ' || cur_r.sumsal);
 11    end loop;
 12  end;
 13  /
Department-wise salary expenditure:
CSE  department, total salary is 99000
IT   department, total salary is 23450
MECH department, total salary is 88560

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

(`rpad` is here just to nicely align the output)

---

As of code you've written: it won't compile, too many errors. Fixed (but still not doing what you need) would be

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    Dept varchar2(25);
  3    Employee_salary VARCHAR2(25);
  4  begin
  5    SELECT salary
  6    into employee_salary
  7    FROM Employee
  8    WHERE salary=23450;
  9
 10    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department-wise salary expenditure :' || employee_salary);
 11  END;
 12  /
Department-wise salary expenditure :23450

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

So, what did you do wrong?

- `begin` needs to be put after the declaration section; your is somewhere down below
- `select` in PL/SQL requires an `into` clause
- `where` clause is useless; you're trying to select salaries which are exactly 23450; if there's none, your query will return `no_data_found` error. If two (or more) employees earn that much, you'll get `too_many_rows` error
- *fancy* single quotes in `dbms_output.put_line`
- you're displaying variable that doesn't exist (and can't be split into two separate names, `dept salary`

Comment: Thank you for your Guidance Sir.I got the Output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using PL/SQL, unless that is a requirement of the exercise.  You seem to only want an aggregation query:

```
SELECT dept, SUM(Employee_salary) as total_salary
FROM Employee;
GROUP BY dept;
```